# Which fonts are the most common ones across different devices?

Tags: website-design, mobile, fonts

What is the most common font on different desktop and mobile devices.
I need my website texts to have the same look and size on different devices.

Answer (score 3):

This is a subject that could end up on discussions, but I'd say; considering the widespread use of Windows, the agreements that Apple has with Microsoft, the early versions distributed from Microsoft and the different ways to install fonts on Linux, that the best options, are the [Core fonts for the Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web) from Microsoft. Specifically the [Georgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_%28typeface%29) and [Verdana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verdana).

Georgia

[image: Georgia]

Verdana

[image: Verdana]

Answer (score 1):

I am usually going to say Verdana for the most common font people use, for the ease of reading.

As for web design, you can assign a font to your CSS StyleSheets using [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) and [how to use them](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started), if you want it to be 'globalized' between all devices.

Answer (score 0):

[Open Sans](http://typecast.com/preview/google/Open%20Sans), [Oswald](http://typecast.com/preview/google/Oswald), [Droid Sans](http://typecast.com/preview/google/Droid%20Sans) are in the Top 3 respectively.

[Roboto Family](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto) is upcoming widely used font.

Among the above, Droid Sans & Oswald seems to cover moderately among all the browsers.

All data are taken from [Google Fonts analytics](https://www.google.com/fonts#Analytics%3atotal), refer it, change the filters & check it for yourself.

> I would go with **Open Sans** as **Oswald** renders badly in Chrome(*atleast for me*).

Comment: I think the OP is referring to which fonts are common (ie. installed by default) to all devices, without having to explicitly import/install them (eg. with Google Fonts). None of the fonts you mention are available on Windows by default.

Answer (score 0):

On websites you have three main ways to specify fonts.  You can specify fonts that are installed on a person's computer, you can use a font service to pull in a custom font, or you can pull in specific fonts you want.